# What are some of the most suitable platforms for creating strategy/simulation games?

Tags: game-engine, game-physics

I have a decently planned idea for a strategy/simulation game. However, I don't want to use a "game-builder-package" to do this, as I think those will limit what I can do, and also because they are aimed towards people with no programming experience. What platforms/languages do you think would be appropriate for a game like this? I'd like to have graphics, but they can be 2D or sprite based to begin with.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 2d game, then right now I'd pick javascript/html5. Your game will run on Win8, android, facebook...

Or, even if I'm not a huge fan, this one could do very well too: [haxe language](http://haxe.org/)